Debugging and finding source code of an onclick event handler in a React and Webpack project in Chrome Dev Tools
I'd like to debug a logic-related bug on a React website. The site is not responding as expected when the user clicks on a button. Is there an efficient way of finding where the onclick function is located in the project directory when I have already isolated the React component in question on the Component tab in Chrome Dev Tools?
I followed this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70922094/2206865
And clicked on "Go to definition"
And when I looked at the source URL it is: webpack-internal:///node_modules/react-native-web/dist/modules/usePressEvents/PressResponder.js
How do I get the original source path and line?
I used webpack-dev-server to serve the source files.
